# Клиент для сайта (парсилка)

Tags: android, html, парсер

Приветствую! Есть нужда в написании некого клиента [к сайту]. 
Пробовал переделывать под сайт статью с хабра, ничего не получилось. Там через компоненту `cleanhtml` работает. Попробовал еще пару компонент (из кусков примера), но так и не пойму, по какому принципу надо парсить. Помогите, плиз, советом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org/).